# Angular 2 cli crashes on Debian server

Tags: angular, debian

I am trying to set up a development pipeline on a Debian server using Git, Jenkins etc... One part of the project I want to build and deploy on this server uses Angular 2, so I tried installing all the necessary components to build this projects. I have installed, in order, npm, nodejs, node-legacy (needed to install the next package) and finally angular2-cli and it is this last part that fails on me. Whenever I try to execute ng2 --help (or ng2 in any form) I get the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular2-cli/lib/cli/index.js:5
const ng2     = require('export-files')(`${__dirname}/commands`);
                                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular2-cli/bin/ng2:2:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Does anyone know what this error means, where it comes from and how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same issue today, did you find a solution? Thank you!